# What does 再 mean if it's added after 后?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I wanted to chat my friend with "Let's chat together when (after) you are home!".
First, I wrote this sentence :
"你回家后咱们一起聊聊吧～"
//
But then when I tried to check my sentence with translation tools (Google Translate and Naver), they added "再" after "后" and thus changing my sentence into this :
"你回家后(再)咱们一起聊聊吧～"
//
Okay, I don't know whether my own sentence is correct or not but... Is what the translation tools said is correct? Should I add 再? And if I should, what does 再 indicate here?

Comment: google translate result:Let's chat together when (after) you are home!当你回家后，我们一起聊天吧！ no 再

Comment: What... Hmmm my Google Translate didn't show me 当... It shows me 再 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**再** means "**again**" or "**continue to**". 回家后咱们**再**一起聊聊吧 means "*Let's chat again when you are home*". You two may continue what you have discussed or talk about other topics.

Your sentence "你回家后咱们一起聊聊吧" denotes the same meaning as your English sentence "*Let's chat together when (after) you are home!*".

Comment: 确定是again的意思？比如你在路上碰见个熟人，想和他聊，但他觉得两个人当时都比较忙，说“我们回家后再聊吧。”，这里的“再”并非again的意思，而是把这件事推迟。

Comment: @马化腾, this is a dictionary definition of 再： 　1. 表示又一次，有时专指第二次，有时又指多次：～次。～衰三竭。
　2. 表示重复或继续，多指未然：～说。
　3. 表示更，更加：～勇敢一点。
　4. 表示承接前一个动作：想好了～写。

Comment: 对呀，我说的这种情况就是第4种，回家后再承接聊天

Comment: @马化腾， I think the definition 2 : 表示重复或继续，多指未然：～说。 fits the OP's context. When it's turned to English, it could be *again*, *later* or *continue to do* based on the context.

Comment: again还能表示later呢？不是then么？

Comment: 你英语这么好，可以问问again能不能表示“想好再写”的“再”

Comment: @马化腾, 有一种情形： 我们讨论一个问题，但是没有讨论完（可能是时间不够了, 或者是没有达成一致）。然后，我可以说：“回家后咱们再一起聊聊吧”. 意思是我们回去后再继续聊， 或者说我们针对这个问题再聊一次。所以我觉得“再”可以理解为要么 “continue to" 要么 ”again".

Comment: 我的意思是，这句话本来就有两个意思。中文经常一句话有两个意思。你已经说了again那个意思了。我说，还有一种情况，就是我说的那种，两个人还没聊呢，那就是接续的意思。两个意思都应该给解释出来。

Comment: @马化腾，我可以把continue to 加上。但我认为“想好再写”和“回家后咱们再一起聊聊吧”两个短语中， “再”的用法是不一样的。

Comment: @马化腾, “想好再写” is like a suggestion or an instruction. It's like saying: "*you should mull it over before writing it down.*" Well, “回家后咱们再一起聊聊吧” is saying: "*we will continue our talk after we get home. or we will talk about it one more time(again) after we get home*".

Comment: @马化腾, 你说的那种情况 “**两个人还没聊呢**”， 可以理解为我们现在聊的是别的话题（或者只是简单的打个招呼）。 可能是我们现在没有时间聊我们想要聊的话题， 所以我提出：“回家后咱们再一起聊聊吧”， 意思是我们到晚上的时候针对这件事情再继续聊一次。从这个角度，again or continue to也是可以解释得通的。

Answer (score 1):

回家后咱们再一起聊聊吧

To me, there are 2 meanings.

```
 1. After you go to home, we continue this conversation.
 2. After you go to home, we do more conversation.
```